# CiviContribute adding $200 even to every transaction

Tags: civicontribute, stripe

CiviCRM 5.24.4/WP 5.4

Some freakish behavior going on with CiviContribute and Stripe processing. Based on Stripe logs, it *looks* like its originating with CiviContribute. Everything worked for at least one test transaction before I upgraded to 5.24.4, but, despite several restores and reconfigurations, I haven't been able to charge the right amount.

Here's the deal: if a user opts to make a $25 contribution, CiviContribute sends the charge to Stripe as $225. If they opt for $100, the charge is $300. Exactly $200 every time. Pretty weird.

Comment: are you using any extensions that affect contributions?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of (TinyMCE, Stripe, Firewall, MJWShared, FlexMailer, and Mosaico).

Comment: and is this pure civi, not eg a webform_civicrm (Drupal) or Caldera_civicrm (WP)

Comment: Straight up civi, created and controlled through CiviContribute.

Comment: really no idea what to suggest without doing some audit of the process. sorry

Comment: appreciate it anyway!

really drilling down now; if I manage to learn anything, I'll share it here.

Comment: What amount is recorded for the Contribution?  What Line Items does it have? What happens if you use a different processor other than Stripe?  Is this via a Contribution Page?  If so, does it happen with all Contribution Pages?

Comment: We just have the one contribution page--and the one payment processor--at the moment; just getting Stripe going was a bit of a challenge. I can confirm that it did work correctly for one test charge.

For the record of the test contribution, everything is correct. I'm still looking at Stripe logs and trying to keep a thread alive in reporting on extension bugs. I'll update this one if I learn anything there.

Comment: Chatted with Stripe for a while about this, and they pointed to the error message I've been seeing (and reported in another thread here): "Credit Card This PaymentIntent's amount could not be updated because it has a status of requires_capture. You may only update the amount of a PaymentIntent with one of the following statuses: requires_payment_method, requires_confirmation, requires_action."

Specifically, they said that the error is coming from 'amount_capture' status. And then I lost the connection with them. No idea what would have caused a $200 bump.

Comment: That Stripe message indicates problems but it seems unlikely that is the cause of your extra $200.  Try setting up another Contribution Page & also test with the dummy processor.  Are you on the latest version of the Stripe extension?  What do you get if you enable debugging: https://docs.civicrm.org/stripe/en/latest/#troubleshooting

Comment: I had no idea there was a dummy processor option! I'll engage that and report back.

With debugging enabled, the most interesting thing I can confirm is "2020-04-24T13:01:45.083Z civicrm_stripe.js: getTotalAmount: 250" (this is with $50 selected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem turned out to be js conflicts with Themefy popup messing up the js files in civicrm.

Disabling the plugin from /wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s removes this problem and contributions go through to Stripe as intended